# htaccess rewrite questions

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I've got an old Joomla site that I would like to move to WordPress. We have lots of old news items in our Joomla site like so…

```
/home/news-and-offers/news/476-new-bridal-boutique-posh-frocks-has-opened.html
/home/news-and-offers/news/594-fabulous-new-offer-from-hall-hotel-and-spa-in-birmingham.html
/home/news-and-offers/news/596-win-your-dress-for-free-this-week-at-berketex-bride.html
/home/news-and-offers/news/602-ask-alice-get-your-big-day-questions-answered.html
/home/news-and-offers/news/637-get-down-to-the-west-countrys-largest-wedding-exhibitions.html
```

that I would like to bulk redirect to…

```
/category/wedding-news/
```

How would I go about writing a regex for this to happen as I don't want to have to add all these articles to my htaccess file.

Thanks in advance, James

Comment: So basically anything starting with ´/home/news-and-offerings´ should be redirected? Do you intend to keep the ids, or just send evetything to the same place?

Comment: `/home` is a folder in the URL-path or `home` in the system path? In short, all URLs with something in `/news/` should be redirected?

Comment: Hi faa, it's in the system path - not a folder - it was added by joomla

Comment: Hi mariusnn, yes everything should be redirected to the one directory. I'm not worried about keeping the id's, as the news articles won't be carried over to the new site, I just don't want to end up with lots of 404s

Answer (score 0):

Putting something like this in `/.htaccess` redirects everything in `/home/news-and-offers` to `/category/wedding-news`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/home/news-and-offers/ /category/wedding-news/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Hi mariusnn,thank for your reply. I've tried it but it's not working :-(

Comment: Are you getting any error-messages or anything?
Do joomla have a .htaccess-config somewhere? (Or even in the apache host-config file)

Comment: No error messages - It's a WordPress htacess file that I'm writing this in. Do you need to see the contents?

Comment: You probably need to remove some of the wordpress-stuff as it is taking presedence of the stuff you want to achieve. It wouldn't hurt to start from there, so feel free to update your question with the existing content.

Comment: and also the location og this file (relative to the root of the webserver).